# loading a page outside of a div in a div

Tags: jquery, load

I'm loading a page outside of a div in a div but it turns out that while the div is loaded correctly, the click event of the button that is inside the outer div does not occur. This is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#boton").click(function(event) {
$("#capa").load('Default2.aspx #contenido');

});
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="capa">Pulsa Actualizar capa


</div>
```

and inside the div "content" there is only one button with code msgbox ("Hello")

Comment: post ALL the code, otherwise figuring this out will be a nightmare

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

In a normal situation, events are defined only for elements already present in the page. If you add an element dinamically (via JavaScript/AJAX), the "new" elements cannot have event handlers assigned to because they "do not exist" when the event is defined.

One solution is to bind the event beforehand.

```
$("#capa").on("click", "#yourloadedbutton", function(...) { doSomething(); });
```

I assume that you load the other page in `#capa` and the page you load has a button with an ID like `#yourloadedbutton`.

Note the selector as 2ns parameter: it says "whenever I click an element that is child of `#capa`, and this elements matches my selector `#yourloadedbutton`, handle this event).

Comment: Thanks, I understand that you can do this procedure, but I have that button or server code, this button makes a query to a database and displays the results. Could not call a function. the only solution I find is inserted into the div all external html page, but I wonder if it is right to do that. Otherwise, what would be the correct way knowing that I make a single web page without using iframes?